# Curtainjs doesn't load when changing page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, curtains.js

So I'm using curtainjs on my website. I have a landing page that redirect to my about page, but when I go to my about page from the landing page, the curtainjs doesn't work. But as soon as I reload the page everything works fine.

Here's how I implemented curtainjs :

```
mounted(){
    window.addEventListener("load", this.curtainjs);
}
methods: {
   curtainjs() {
      const curtains = new Curtains({
        container: "canvas",
        pixelRatio: Math.min(1.5, window.devicePixelRatio),
      });

      curtains
        .onRender(() => {
          // update our planes deformation
          // increase/decrease the effect
          planesDeformations = curtains.lerp(planesDeformations, 0, 0.075);
        })
        .onScroll(() => {
          // get scroll deltas to apply the effect on scroll
          const delta = curtains.getScrollDeltas();

          // invert value for the effect
          delta.y = -delta.y;

          // threshold
          if (delta.y > 60) {
            delta.y = 60;
          } else if (delta.y < -60) {
            delta.y = -60;
          }

          if (Math.abs(delta.y) > Math.abs(planesDeformations)) {
            planesDeformations = curtains.lerp(
              planesDeformations,
              delta.y,
              0.1
            );
          }
        })
        .onError(() => {
          // we will add a class to the document body to display original images
          document.body.classList.add("no-curtains", "planes-loaded");
        })
        .onContextLost(() => {
          // on context lost, try to restore the context
          curtains.restoreContext();
        });

      const planes = [];
      let planesDeformations = 0;

      // get our planes elements
      let planeElements = document.getElementsByClassName("plane");

      const vs = `
        precision mediump float;
    
        // default mandatory variables
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
    
        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
    
        uniform mat4 planeTextureMatrix;
    
        // custom variables
        varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    
        uniform float uPlaneDeformation;
    
        void main() {
            vec3 vertexPosition = aVertexPosition;
    
            // cool effect on scroll
            vertexPosition.y += sin(((vertexPosition.x + 1.0) / 2.0) * 3.141592) * (sin(uPlaneDeformation / 90.0));
    
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
    
            // varyings
            vVertexPosition = vertexPosition;
            vTextureCoord = (planeTextureMatrix * vec4(aTextureCoord, 0.0, 1.0)).xy;
        }
    `;

      const fs = `
        precision mediump float;
    
        varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    
        uniform sampler2D planeTexture;
    
        void main() {
            // just display our texture
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(planeTexture, vTextureCoord);
        }
    `;

      // all planes will have the same parameters
      const params = {
        vertexShader: vs,
        fragmentShader: fs,
        widthSegments: 10,
        heightSegments: 10,
        fov: 45,
        drawCheckMargins: {
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
        },
        uniforms: {
          planeDeformation: {
            name: "uPlaneDeformation",
            type: "1f",
            value: 0,
          },
        },
      };

      // add our planes and handle them
      for (let i = 0; i < planeElements.length; i++) {
        planes.push(new Plane(curtains, planeElements[i], params));

        handlePlanes(i);
      }

      // handle all the planes
      function handlePlanes(index) {
        const plane = planes[index];

        // check if our plane is defined and use it
        plane
          .onReady(() => {
            // once everything is ready, display everything
            if (index === planes.length - 1) {
              document.body.classList.add("planes-loaded");
              document.querySelectorAll(".picture").forEach((img) => {
                img.style.display = "none";
              });
            }
          })
          .onRender(() => {
            // update the uniform
            plane.uniforms.planeDeformation.value = planesDeformations;
          });
      }
    },
}
```

I don't know where it coould come from because there is no other place to put the function call than the mounted part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the window `load` event has already been fired when you navigate from your landing page to the about page.

You could directly call `this.curtainsjs()` inside your `mounted` hook and this should work.

However this pattern will lead to memory leaks every time you'll navigate away from the about page since the `curtains` instance won't be correctly disposed.
There's at least a couple solutions to avoid this:

### Solution 1 - quick and dirty

Assign your `curtains` instance to a private component variable and dispose the instance before unmounting the component.

This should work but it's far from being perfect in terms of performances and ressources, as you'll recreate a new `webgl` context each time you'll navigate to the about page.

```js
mounted(){
    this.curtainjs();
},
beforeUnmount() {
    if(this.$curtains) {
        // dispose curtains instance
        this.$curtains.dispose();
    }
},
methods: {
   curtainjs() {
      this.$curtains = new Curtains({
        container: "canvas",
        pixelRatio: Math.min(1.5, window.devicePixelRatio),
      });

      this.$curtains
        .onRender(() => {
          // update our planes deformation
          // increase/decrease the effect
          planesDeformations = this.$curtains.lerp(planesDeformations, 0, 0.075);
        })
        .onScroll(() => {
          // get scroll deltas to apply the effect on scroll
          const delta = this.$curtains.getScrollDeltas();

          // invert value for the effect
          delta.y = -delta.y;

          // threshold
          if (delta.y > 60) {
            delta.y = 60;
          } else if (delta.y < -60) {
            delta.y = -60;
          }

          if (Math.abs(delta.y) > Math.abs(planesDeformations)) {
            planesDeformations = curtains.lerp(
              planesDeformations,
              delta.y,
              0.1
            );
          }
        })
        .onError(() => {
          // we will add a class to the document body to display original images
          document.body.classList.add("no-curtains", "planes-loaded");
        })
        .onContextLost(() => {
          // on context lost, try to restore the context
          this.$curtains.restoreContext();
        });

      const planes = [];
      let planesDeformations = 0;

      // get our planes elements
      let planeElements = document.getElementsByClassName("plane");

      const vs = `
        precision mediump float;
    
        // default mandatory variables
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
    
        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
    
        uniform mat4 planeTextureMatrix;
    
        // custom variables
        varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    
        uniform float uPlaneDeformation;
    
        void main() {
            vec3 vertexPosition = aVertexPosition;
    
            // cool effect on scroll
            vertexPosition.y += sin(((vertexPosition.x + 1.0) / 2.0) * 3.141592) * (sin(uPlaneDeformation / 90.0));
    
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
    
            // varyings
            vVertexPosition = vertexPosition;
            vTextureCoord = (planeTextureMatrix * vec4(aTextureCoord, 0.0, 1.0)).xy;
        }
    `;

      const fs = `
        precision mediump float;
    
        varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    
        uniform sampler2D planeTexture;
    
        void main() {
            // just display our texture
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(planeTexture, vTextureCoord);
        }
    `;

      // all planes will have the same parameters
      const params = {
        vertexShader: vs,
        fragmentShader: fs,
        widthSegments: 10,
        heightSegments: 10,
        fov: 45,
        drawCheckMargins: {
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
        },
        uniforms: {
          planeDeformation: {
            name: "uPlaneDeformation",
            type: "1f",
            value: 0,
          },
        },
      };

      // add our planes and handle them
      for (let i = 0; i < planeElements.length; i++) {
        planes.push(new Plane(this.$curtains, planeElements[i], params));

        handlePlanes(i);
      }

      // handle all the planes
      function handlePlanes(index) {
        const plane = planes[index];

        // check if our plane is defined and use it
        plane
          .onReady(() => {
            // once everything is ready, display everything
            if (index === planes.length - 1) {
              document.body.classList.add("planes-loaded");
              document.querySelectorAll(".picture").forEach((img) => {
                img.style.display = "none";
              });
            }
          })
          .onRender(() => {
            // update the uniform
            plane.uniforms.planeDeformation.value = planesDeformations;
          });
      }
    },
}
```

### Solution 2 - the right way

The correct "Vue" way to handle this would be to create a `curtains` plugin and a `Curtains` component at the root of your `App` where you'll handle the `webgl` context creation only once on init.

Then you could create as many `Plane` components as needed with their own lifecycle methods (creation and removal using `mounted` and `beforeUnmount` hooks) using your plugin.

I won't write the whole code here (it shouldn't be that difficult), even tho I realize a `Vue` example usecase of the library might be useful. I'll think about it.

Also, looking at your code it seems you've just copied/pasted one of the library example into your `curtainsjs` method. There's a lot of room for improvement here: handle errors/events and variables with Vue `data`, `computed` and `methods` properties, import the shaders from external files, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot fot the solution and all the advices. Just a little question though, how do you import shaders from external files ?

Comment: You could create a `shaders.js` file and export your `const vs` and `const fs` from there for example. Or you could configure your project to use https://github.com/glslify/glslify

Comment: So I've created the plugin but it does the same thing as before. It only works when I reload the page. I tried to put a timeout but that doesn't change